# An open map from $\mathbb{C} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ has open real and imaginary part?

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, functions

If $f(z) :\mathbb{C} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ is an open map such that $f(z) = f_1(z) + if_2(z)$ where $f_1$ and $f_2$ represent respectively his real and imaginary part, we could say that both $f_1$ and $f_2$ are open maps?

If $f$ is holomorphic, his real and imaginary part are holomorphic?

Comment: Yes, each $f_k$ is the composition $p_k\circ f$, where $p_k$ is the projection onto the $k$-th coordinate, and a projection is open. This assumes that you know that the topology on $\Bbb C$ is the product topology on $\Bbb R^2$.

Comment: if f is holomorphic are his real and imaginary part holomorphic?

Comment: If $f$ is holomorphic, his/her/its real and imaginary components are harmonic and form a pair of harmonic conjugates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Summarizing the comments: yes, $f_1$ and $f_2$ are open maps from $\mathbb C$ to $\mathbb R$, being the compositions of $f$ with projections (which are open maps).

No, a real valued function cannot be holomorphic unless it is constant. This can be seen from the Cauchy-Riemann equations. Instead, the real and imaginary parts of a holomorphic function are *harmonic* functions, which form an important class of their own.